# displaying category on a cms page in magento

Tags: magento

I am using a CMS page and i want to show some particular Categories on that page.Can anyone plz guide me how can i do it with the category image as well

thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

You should use static blocks.

What categories do you want to display?
Is this a list of predefined category ids?